# UITableView which UITableViewCells can save and load data from core data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, uitableview

I'm looking for a demo project/tuturial of a table view where the cells have several textboxs so it looks like a grid. each line can be edited and save(locally but DB is better).

I found this project before ... but I lost it :_(

I've looked for it in the web for hours now and if you can help me I would appriciate it alot

I think I first found it in:
http://open.iphonedev.com/

But can't find it now...it should look like this:
[alt text http://www.flickr.com/photos/48660221@N06/4804793849/](http://www.flickr.com/photos/48660221@N06/4804793849/)
[alt text http://www.flickr.com/photos/48660221@N06/4804793569/](http://www.flickr.com/photos/48660221@N06/4804793569/)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably one of these projects: http://open.iphonedev.com/search/grid

Comment: I'm not that lazy... - to have the site and ask someone to give me the exact page.

Anyway, thanks for the effort you made for me.

Comment: I didn't think you were lazy. I thought perhaps you could't navigate the site owing to a language barrier. I certainly can't navigate non-English sites very easily. I spent an hour trying to find something on a German site once.

Comment: Well thank you, it is just so frustrating having the holy grail in your hands and loose it just like that... I know that a year from now I'll just sit for one hour and make it happen but right now... It's just too difficult.
bla bla bla ... the button line - thank you!